# C#: How to create a window like this?

Tags: c#, windows

I need to create a window similar to this:
[image]

a window similar to the types of dialog boxes that have been included with windows vista.

[image: inputwindow]
[image: creditanol]
but I could not find exactly the same dialog boxes. very similar - it's Credential dialog and Input dialog. In the first case there are differences in the UI, in the second - the number of input fields and the absence of label. How can I make exactly the same window? Sorry for bad English.

Comment: You could try to extend the existing controls but maybe it would be easier to create your own windows in WPF. And to create and design them you can use Expression blend. The dialog windows you could show from code with 'ShowDialog' and then they would behave like other Dialogs in windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to create a dialog *exactly* like the first dialog you've shown, the one used by FluffyApp?

**You'll have to create it yourself, by hand.** It's not a standard Windows dialog; it's a custom dialog resource provided by the FluffyApp application. It's obviously modeled to look a lot like the standard Windows authentication dialog, which is a good idea—users are already familiar with the native UI and will find your application to be much easier to use if it strongly resembles what they're already accustomed to. I recommend that if you decide to create your own custom dialog that you follow Windows's example as well.

But it's not entirely clear why you need your dialog to look exactly like the one that FluffyApp uses. I'm not really even sure why FluffyApp needed to create a custom dialog! It seems like the standard Windows authentication dialog would be perfectly sufficient. They have the same number of input fields, the UI designers at Microsoft have just replaced labels with [cue banners](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761639.aspx). Not anything to worry about.

Comment: Why a custom dialog? Because I needed to have links :) I've scrapped that login dialog now in any case.

Answer (score 0):

Those are standard windows dialogs, but instead of letting the dialog manager draw the text, they use DrawThemeText to draw the text, using one of the themed elements (not sure what, because you have several examples).  You can play around with the various parameters to DrawThemeText to come up with something that works.